# How to install Azhagi+ font in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: software-installation

Please let me know how to install azhagi+ font in ubuntu11.10.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Ubuntu 11.10 which is not supported since May 2013.  I suggest you upgrade

Answer (score 1):

1. Download azhagi+ font.
2. The font file should be with extension azhagi.ttf.
3. In Home folder create a new folder and remame it ".fonts".
4. Move the font file azhagi.ttf to the folder .fonts.
5. Restart your computer.